# How do I use getvalue using Ace Editor?

Tags: javascript, editor, ace-editor

I am using the Ace Editor, but I do no use JavaScript a lot so I'm finding it hard to make it actually work without a proper documentation.

I'm working on a local PHP file editor.. so open files etc, works fine, setcontent works like a charm. But now I want to save the editor's information back to the file.

In itself not really a problem. But how do I retrieve the var code.
If I use document.write it will not show the current information in the editor

If I could print out what is in the editor I could save the data. But I don't know how to provide a valid callback for getValue

Can someone please give me a little bit more information on what to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply say:

```
editor.getSession().on('change', function(){ 
         editor.getSession().getValue(); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`editor.getSession().getValue()`

Where `editor` is the instance of the editor.  If you're using jQuery along side of Ace, what I've been doing is preserving the editor instance on the DOM element.

```
var editor = ace.edit('...');
$('#editor').data('editor', editor);
```

Later on if you need to get the value back you can then just do...

```
$('#editor').data('editor').getSession().getValue();
```

Comment: I used the following code but it does not seem to work, when I use jQuery's .html it does display whatever I put into it, but not the value of the editor. I'm probably doing it wrong or something.

`editor.getSession().on('change', function(){
    $('#content').data(editor).getSession().getValue();
});`

Thanks for replying btw.

Comment: You don't need to store the editor in the element's `data` bag. To get the instance, simple say `var editor = ace.edit('target');` where `target` is the DOM element that created the editor instance.

Comment: @Mrchief nice comment. you should have answered too.

Comment: @Mrchief, oh, i did not see that, +1 then :)