# How to get Ace Editor object from its Div id

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `div` which instantiates an ace editor object.

I am trying to `drag and drop` some text into it from an `HTML draggable`.

I have made the `ui-ace div droppable` and want to get the current instance of the editor from the event target of drop.

How can I accomplish this???

**HTML**

```
<div id="id1" ui-ace droppable=true ondrop="handleDrop(event,this)"></div>
```

**JS function**

```
function handleDrop(e,obj){
   // need code to get current editor instance from obj without using ace.edit(obj.id)
   // because ace.edit(obj.id) will reset the content I believe. Please correct me if I am 
   //wrong. Ace api says it will insert editor in the DOM. http://ace.c9.io/#nav=api&api=ace
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 25):

I don't know why this is not mentioned in the API documentation, but if you call `ace.edit` on an already instantiated editor, you will get that instance. It will NOT reset that editor. I have tested it.

In your case, it could be accomplished by the following code:

```
function handleDrop(e,obj)
{
   var editor = ace.edit(obj.id);

   // Do something with editor
}
```

I know it has been a while since you have asked this question, but I couldn't find anything on this topic so I thought I should share this.

Comment: Or quote from [T. Stone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007742/how-do-i-use-getvalue-using-ace-editor) if you use jQuery as well.